# Mysql no data insert

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with insert into to mysql.

Here's my code and the problem:

http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/4396/b07u.png

It's empty...If I fill the data in the form. But he remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

Please help me :D

Some code:

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","janveuf58_forum1","admin1","janveuf58_hacks");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO hack (name, download, virustotal)
VALUES
('$_POST['name']','$_POST['download']','$_POST['virustotal']')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
header('Location: http://www.warrock-hack.net/beheer/');

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

And the HTML;

```
<form action="addhack.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Download: <input type="text" name="download">
Virustotal: <input type="text" name="virustotal">
<input type="submit">
```

Comment: Please, write your code in the post, instead of linking an image

Comment: If you can post an image post the code here

Comment: Comment out the header redirect. There might be an error you're not seeing because it's redirecting

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from your use of $_POST, with paramters, inside of an SQL string.
Try setting the three $_POST items to variables:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$download = $_POST['download'];
$virus_total = $_POST['virustotal'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO hack (name,download,virustotal)
      VALUES
      ('$name','$download','$virus_total')";
```

Comment: Is it throwing an error or just not entering any data?